# What is the technique and required materials to connect a new PVC elbow to an existing PVC T-Pipe?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, pvc

When connecting a new PVC elbow to an existing PVC T-Pipe, is there any special technique required or any materials (such as plumber's putty) required to complete this task?

I'm imagining it's very simple, but since I've never done this, I am choosing to ask before jumping in.

The piping is the drainpipe for a sink, after the garbage disposal.

Photo of the plumbing layout:
[image: Photo of the plumbing layout]

Thanks.

Comment: @GWarner Thanks for your interest.  Yes, it is a drainpipe for a sink, after the garbage disposal.

Comment: I am only a DIYer but I would never use plumbers putty between two PVC fittings. It is used to prevent leaking between metal fittings (The sink and disposal top) What exactly is this set up with the existing T fitting? Got a picture?

Comment: There are two likely possibilities  here - cemented PVC drain pipes, and slip-joint compression polypropylene (or metal, but you'd be unlikely to confuse those for PVC) trap parts. There will be short threads and nuts associated with those. It's not clear which parts you are asking about. Please [edit] to add a picture.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thanks.  No problem.  Photo added.

Answer (score 2):

You should only join same type fittings with the correct [cement](https://www.hunker.com/12317123/types-of-pvc-cement). PVC is white, CPVC is almost tan or dark off white, ABS is black.

The threaded PVC-like fittings *(they are actually polypropylene)* use a silicone or plastic compression gasket or fitting to seal the connection.

Plumber's putty is not durable enough to seal two fittings. The various pipe cements actually fuse the two pieces into one. Even the minute vibrations from a garbage disposal would cause the plumbers putty seal to break.

Comment: Discovered this post . It's a good exmaple how *not* to plumb a disposal. With a correct plumbing example. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/227224/what-s-wrong-with-the-plumbing-setup-under-this-kitchen-sink

Comment: Thanks. That's an impressive example!

Comment: Yea I have seen some really hobbled together set ups. What's the progress on your project?

Comment: Good question!  I just posted this additional question to ask for help from those of you with appropriate knowledge or experience: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/227286/will-the-insinkerator-evolution-compact-garbage-disposal-fit-under-this-sink-wit

Comment: I completely re-vamped my answer to include PVC, ABS, and CPVC types.