# Will the InSinkErator Evolution Compact garbage disposal fit under this sink without modifying the plumbing?

Tags: plumbing, water, plumbing-fixture, garbage-disposal, sewer

I'm trying to help out an elderly friend with a plumbing issue.  He doesn't know anything about plumbing, and I don't consider myself very knowledgeable in the field.

His sink currently has an InSinkErator Badger 5 garbage disposal that requires replacement.  Will the ISE Evolution Compact garbage disposal fit under this sink without modifying the plumbing?

The [InSinkErator website](https://blog.insinkerator.com/how-to-replace-badger-garbage-disposal-evolution-compact/) claims:

> [The Evolution Compact] has the same rough-in plumbing dimensions as Badger models so it can be easily interchanged with any Badger disposal without altering the plumbing connections.

Looking at the diagrams in the manuals, he and I both wonder if this is true.

As you can see, the Badger 5 has a 5" horizontal distance between the two vertical centerlines:

[image: Badger 5 garbage disposal diagram]
*Source: [InSinkErator Badger 5 manual](https://insinkerator.emerson.com/documents/badger-installation-care-use-manual-en-us-6959418.pdf)*

**Whereas the Evolution Compact has a 5.75" horizontal distance:**

[image: Evolution Compact garbage disposal diagram]
*Source: [InSinkErator Evolution Compact manual](https://insinkerator.emerson.com/documents/evolution-compact-installation-care-use-manual-en-us-6867438.pdf)*

**There is also the 1.75" difference in diameter between the 2 units to contend with**, but I can't tell if that will also be an issue.

Here are 2 photos of the plumbing pipe layout:

[image: Plumbing pipe layout photo 1]
[image: Plumbing pipe layout photo 2]

Will the InSinkErator Evolution Compact garbage disposal fit under this sink without modifying the plumbing?

If not, what would be required to make it fit?

Comment: Nice to see all the info needed to answer the question with focused pictures, and nice to see someone's double sink plumbed properly without a drip pan underneath!

Comment: Is this the photos concerning your other question?

Comment: Already have the replacement disposal? I think you will just have to jump into this with both feet. But prepared to go to a hardware store.

Comment: Is that P-Trap cemented? Its actually a two piece unit *https://www.homedepot.com/p/NIBCO-2-in-ABS-Hub-x-Hub-P-Trap-C5885HD2/100344056* If you dont have enough wiggle room with the threaded fittings. It looks like getting a new Ptrap and cementing the two pieces at a different angle would give you the space you need.

Comment: I would personally replace that (looks fixed/glued) trap with a union trap, to allow more options in where things line up by swiveling the union (which you don't glue - nor do you glue any of the compression/sliding joints - just the PVC pipe joints at each end of the trap, and the PVC pipe joint to the compression trap adapter.) But most of that PVC is probably actually ABS, since it's black. Uses different glue. What is the base color of the pipe out of the wall? It looks like it might be painted so I won't assume white, even though it looks white. Normally stick to the same type of plastic.

Comment: @jay613 Thanks Jay.  It involved much time and effort to get all the details together for a quality post, so I'm glad to hear it was appreciated.  And thank *you* for the first answer, which I'm going to read right now.

Comment: @GWarner Yes, these are the photos.  Thank you for your interest.  We don't already have the other disposal, and will buying it from a private party who couldn't get it to fit under his sink, so returning it won't be an option.

Comment: Some one care to take this to a personal chatroom just for this discussion? It might help OP. I know I am getting lost looking at all the comments. Rockpaper I hope you are keeping track.

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/s/nibco%2520abs%2520p%2520trap?NCNI-5 OP's is the cemented type. But I see a coupling variety here. If the pipe going into the wall is like mine it is cast iron ?(1950's construction)

Comment: @GWarner Looking at all the photos (I'm not physically there, but I have a bunch of photos), it appears the end of the P-trap that leads to the T is cemented, but the end of the P-trap that eventually leads to the sewage system looks like it is attached with a nut.  Regarding the pipe that comes out of the wall, I can't tell from the photos what it is... it definitely looks painted, but the paint or underlying surface has almost a rough fiberglass texture to it; not sure if that means anything to you.

Comment: You could be on to something. If it is cast iron like my own It may very well of been wrapped with fiberglas or similar product and epoxied in place with the elbow fitted while it cured.-

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126577/disposal-change-out-drain-pipe-adjustments

Comment: I created chatroom because I was getting nagged to by the system to stop using comments for extended discussion. And I was getting lost in just what the progress has been.

Answer (score 3):

Can't be guaranteed but it probably will fit using your existing plumbing fittings.  You have tons of space and plenty of vertical drop to the wall drain.  Everything you have there is compression/slip joints that have some room to slip in and out and rotate.

The new unit is 3/4" wider so you'll rotate it and the trap to a position where they line up, then you will rotate the T coupling that joins the other sink so that it is pointing directly at the other sink and you'll couple those together.  Should be enough play in all components to make it all go smoothly.

You never know though ... maybe some of those couplings have been cracked or broken or glued or otherwise abused and not reusable.  You need to be prepared to run out to the store for replacement bits if you run into problems.

Don't forget the dishwasher drain hose needs to make a loop up high between the sink and the wall before coming back down to join the new disposal.

Comment: Good answer.  With the new disposal, **DRY FIT** (or only loosely thread the slip joints) any connections that you glue.

Comment: Looking at it from a different perspective: the drain exit is as low as it gets. If it won't fit here it won't fit anywhere. I suggest OP get *all* the fitting for a completely new install, and return what's not used.

Comment: Re glue, the only glued parts I see are the first elbow out of the wall and an extension on one side of the trap.  Neither of these limit you in any way, you can just re-use them, you should not have to glue anything.  With any luck you don't even have to remove anything, just loosen all the couplings, replace the thing, realign and tighten.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jay.  Upvoted.  One of my concerns is that as the T coupling is rotated, it looks like the length of the (nearly) horizontal pipe coming from the other basin will need to be shorter or longer (depending on which direction the T coupling needs to be rotated to make things fit best).  I used to work with steel quite a bit, where everything needed to be exact and there was never any wiggle room.  Based on this added comment, do you think there will be sufficient wiggle room?  Thanks again.

Comment: I was concerned about that too.  If the T joint moves say 1/16 inch further away is there 1/16 inch extra pipe in the coupling?   You could open that T joint now to see how much extra there is.  Even 1/4 inch will be plenty.  If not, go buy a longer one.  Alternately  swivel the disposal 90 degrees clockwise (looking from above the sink).  Then the cross piece will be too long and everything will definitely fit but it will eat up a little of the most convenient floor space in the cabinet. It's nicer to have the disposal exit pointing backwards.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no wiggle room as jay613 suggested you will have no choice but get other parts. The T is not directly centered between both sink drains because the disposal outlet is angled back. The new dispoal will offset the T regardless where you place the outlet

The horizontal pipe can be shortened or replaced with a longer one but you will have to change out the down tube and the P-trap to be able to swivel parts around. Here's a [link](https://www.homedepot.com/s/nibco%2520abs%2520p%2520trap?NCNI-5) to appropriate replacements.

looking straight down. The arc of where that disposal outlet bends down and the arc of that P-trap inlet have to intersect.

EDIT: There are offset fittings that work by shifting a pipe anywhere from  1/4" to 1 inch to the side that could be considered.

Comment: Thanks.  Upvoted.  I'm following everything you are saying except that the down tube and P-trap will have to be replaced.  Can you elaborate why?

Comment: Thanks. I am just doubtful there will be 3/4" wiggle room for pipes to reconnect with the stationary P trap cemented in place. You might be able to get the disposal to lean away from the pipes enough. The sheet metal of the sink bottom will flex a little that it isn't really noticeable,

Comment: EDIT added as additional info.

Comment: Thanks for your note about offset fittings.  I don't think I had heard of those before.