# Does a plumbing hose going from a dishwasher to a garbage disposal require a loop?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, dishwasher, garbage-disposal, hose

In [Jay613's helpful answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/227287/27414) to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/227286/will-the-insinkerator-evolution-compact-garbage-disposal-fit-under-this-sink-wit), Jay writes:

> Don't forget the dishwasher drain hose needs to make a loop up high between the sink and the wall before coming back down to join the new disposal.

Currently, that hose, pictured going to the broken garbage disposal below, is just a short straight rubber hose.

[image: Photo 1 with dishwasher hose leading to garbage disposal]
[image: Photo 2 with dishwasher hose leading to garbage disposal]

Does that hose need to be replaced with a longer hose so a loop can be made?  If so, would that be a vertical loop or horizontal one?  Also, what is the function of such a loop?  If it's supposed to be oriented vertically, it seems like it will act similarly to a P-trap and will always hold some waste.  Is that okay with a rubber hose?

If it is relevant, that dishwasher does have an air gap.

As an aside, you can see what appears to be either discoloration of the hose or some sort of coating.  Is the color variation an indication that the hose requires replacement?  I think the hose is probably about 10-15 years old.

Comment: @jay613 Since I'm quoting you, I figure it's respectful to ping you to let you know! :)

Comment: *that dishwasher does have an air gap.* That is actually the function of a dishwasher high loop. If you actually have a functioning air gap then the rubber hose is **not** directly from the dishwasher, but goes up to the air gap - if so, you are all set. **Upload a picture showing the other end of the hose, air gap, etc.**

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Thanks for your interest.  I requested more photos and just received them.  I'll go through them and upload the best one right away.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Just FYI, [notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) only work for people that have commented on a post or edited it (plus a few more special cases). Attempts to ping other people are simply ignored by SE.

Comment: Generally speaking, the white discoloration you're seeing on that rubber hose is simply what they do as they age. So long as the hose remains soft and flexible (i.e. you can easily squeeze it), you should be fine. You should do the same checks every now and then on the radiator hose in your car, too, so you can catch and replace it before it bursts, leaving you stranded at the side of the road.

Comment: @TooTea Thank you so much.  Learn something new everyday!

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks for the info.  You just taught me two things for the price of one. ;)

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm _very_ curious... The rubber hose is connected to some sort of fitting that is also connected to the ribbed hose that, I presume, comes from the dishwasher. Can you get a pic of that fitting? The fact that the dishwasher drain hose goes up above where it later drains into the disposal _is_ your "loop" or trap in this hose, I've just never known of a fitting like that that appears to be more acute than a 90° angle.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to have an "**Air Gap**" above the counter which the hose is coming from. That is the code approved "better than a loop" method for diswasher drains. You're fine.

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted.  If no one disagrees within a few days, please don't hesitate to remind me to accept your answer.